# Why do 'callback' and 'tweet' fail in my Twitter GPT-3 OpenAI bot?

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-oauth, openai-api, gpt-3

I am trying to develop a Twitter bot using OpenAI gpt-3 library, following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7LEihbOv3Y&t=1s this tutorial.

I am getting this same error again and again.
[I clicked on AUTH link and authorized the bot. When I clicked on the other two links, I got this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cT9lZ.png)
I have recently got Elevated access for my Twitter bot and hence, tried using this bot again.

What should I do?
Please help, thank you.

Code :-

```
=== Serving from '/Users/tanmayjuneja/Documents/demos/twitterbot'...

⚠  Your requested "node" version "16" doesn't match your global version "12". Using node@12 from host.
i  functions: Watching "/Users/tanmayjuneja/Documents/demos/twitterbot/functions" for Cloud Functions...
✔  functions[us-central1-auth]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5000/twitterbot-e8123/us-central1/auth).
✔  functions[us-central1-callback]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5000/twitterbot-e8123/us-central1/callback).
✔  functions[us-central1-tweet]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5000/twitterbot-e8123/us-central1/tweet).
⚠  functions: The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running, so calls to Firestore will affect production.
i  functions: Beginning execution of "auth"
⚠  Google API requested!
   - URL: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
   - Be careful, this may be a production service.
i  functions: Finished "auth" in ~1s
i  functions: Beginning execution of "callback"
⚠  Google API requested!
   - URL: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
   - Be careful, this may be a production service.
i  functions: Finished "callback" in ~3s
i  functions: Beginning execution of "callback"
⚠  functions: Error: Request failed with code 400
    at RequestHandlerHelper.createResponseError (/Users/tanmayjuneja/Documents/demos/twitterbot/functions/node_modules/twitter-api-v2/dist/client-mixins/request-handler.helper.js:103:16)
    at RequestHandlerHelper.onResponseEndHandler (/Users/tanmayjuneja/Documents/demos/twitterbot/functions/node_modules/twitter-api-v2/dist/client-mixins/request-handler.helper.js:252:25)
    at Gunzip.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1221:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
i  functions: Beginning execution of "tweet"
⚠  Google API requested!
   - URL: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
   - Be careful, this may be a production service.
⚠  functions: Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (/Users/tanmayjuneja/Documents/demos/twitterbot/functions/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/Users/tanmayjuneja/Documents/demos/twitterbot/functions/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Users/tanmayjuneja/Documents/demos/twitterbot/functions/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:322:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1221:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```